# MS-Access SQL Error (Update on an Inner Join with aggregate function)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have this SELECT query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT T1.Account, T1.Total, T2.Account, T2.Total
FROM tSummary2 as T1

INNER JOIN
(SELECT tSummary2.Account, 
Count(FinalData.ID) AS Total
FROM tSummary2 
INNER JOIN FinalData 
ON tSummary2.Account = FinalData.Account
GROUP BY tSummary2.Account) as T2

ON T2.Account = T1.Account
```

I need to make T1.Total = T2.Total.
But every attempt to turn this into an update query is failing with "SYNTAX ERROR (missing operator).

Here is what I am trying:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Total = T2.Total
FROM tSummary2 as T1

INNER JOIN
(SELECT tSummary2.Account, 
Count(FinalData.ID) AS Total
FROM tSummary2 
INNER JOIN FinalData 
ON tSummary2.Account = FinalData.Account
GROUP BY tSummary2.Account) as T2

ON T2.Account = T1.Account
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `SELECT` clause it seems.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Total = (SELECT T2.Total
                 FROM tSummary2 as T1
           INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT tSummary2.Account, 
                         Count(FinalData.ID) AS Total
                    FROM tSummary2 
              INNER JOIN FinalData 
                     ON tSummary2.Account = FinalData.Account
               GROUP BY tSummary2.Account) as T2
                     ON T2.Account = T1.Account)
```

I just added the SELECT before T2.Total

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I'm now getting an error "Operation must use an updateable query."

Comment: It's of course unknown that there is only one result for T2.Total. I don't know if Access knows TOP 1? Yuo could try SELECT TOP 1 T2.Total and see what happens?